# What is the most resource intensive task within a script?

Tags: resources, pine-script

I currently am trying to reduce the loading time of my script by offloading tasks to libraries and functions as explained in the pinescript limitations documentation but wondered if someone here knew the most resource intensive tasks for Pinescript as a language like labels, plots, request.security functions etc. Any help would be appreciated

I have tried offloading certain functions and code to libraries and combining req.security functions into one singular function instead of calling it each time.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize your code efficiency, try not to use the `max_bars_back` option in the indicator declaration, and if it's necessary, try to use the function version of `max_bars_back`.
If you have boxes, lines, or labels, try to call the functions inside an `if barstate.islast` block.